# Changing $*DISTRO values for testing

Tags: testing, raku

I need to test a feature that [includes this line](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/0a2eef8fb0adb24164999a2b71c415fd11fe748a#diff-4ce1542a6f014c9a003fe452abe8cac3R2161):

```perl6
if $translate-nl && $*DISTRO.is-win
```

I have tried to reassign a value to $*DISTRO,

```perl6
$*DISTRO='Windows 10';
```

but it says:

```perl6
Cannot modify an immutable Distro (debian (9.stretch))␤
```

[`$*DISTRO`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#index-entry-%24%2ADISTRO) is a dynamic variable, and it makes sense that it's not modified. That said, is there any other way that code can be tested (other than going to Windows, of course)

Answer (score 6):

```
my $*DISTRO = ...
```

Hopefully modifying the original is unnecessary. It's generally unreasonable [action-at-a-distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_(computer_programming)) -- almost certainly so if someone has arranged for it to be an immutable value. This is the reason why [global variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) got such a bad reputation.

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on raiph's answer: the `*` in `$*DISTRO` marks it as a dynamic variable. You can re-declare it any scope, and code called from there will see the redeclared value:

```
{
    my $*DISTRO = ...;
    # coded called from here sees the redeclared value
}
# code called from here sees the original value
```

Now, the question remains, what do you put in place of these pesky `...`?

In the simplest case, a mock that just has whatever the code under test needs:

```
{
    my class Distro { has $.is-win }
    my $*DISTRO = Distro.new( :is-win );
    # call your test code here
}
```

If the code needs more attributes in `Distro`, just add them to the mock `Distro` class.

If the code needs a "real* `Distro` object, for some reason, you can instantiate the built-in one. The constructor `.new` isn't really documented, but [the source code makes it pretty obvious what arguments it expects](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Distro.pm6).

Answer (score -2):

OK, I got the answer relatively fast. [`$*DISTRO` is actually a read-only alias of `PROCESS::<$DISTRO>`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/98e575de00db42101d4879e43fe740a34791c418/src/core/Distro.pm6#L90)

So we only need to do:

```perl6
my $*DISTRO = Distro.new(:is-win,:release<11>,:path-sep('|||'),:auth<unknown>,:name<mswin32>,:desc<Test>,:version<v11>);
say $*DISTRO.is-win; #OUTPUT: «True␤»
```

Comment: No, I wouldn't do that as that is the very definition of "action-at-a-distance": this would then apply to *all* code running for all threads.  The correct way to do this is by doing `my $*DISTRO = Distro.new(:is-win,:release<11>,:path-sep('|||'),:auth<unknown>,:name<mswin32>,:desc<Test>,:version<v11>);` in the scope that you need to have `$*DISTRO` pretend that it's a Windows system.