# Changing a class variable from outside the class

Tags: raku, meta-object-protocol

Finally, when I [managed to understand how to fix this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731999/changing-distro-values-for-testing), that is, how to change the value of an internal dynamic variable, the code has moved on and now it is [declared in this way](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/37fc2883dde6e9acb12e97293068a876e22d8c3c/src/core/Encoding/Builtin.pm6#L25):

```perl6
my int $is-win = Rakudo::Internals.IS-WIN;
```

This is a class variable declared inside `class Encoding::Builtin`. Makes all the sense in the world, since an OS is not something that changes during the lifetime of a variable. However, I need to test this code from other OS, so I would need to access that class variable and assign it a `True` value. Can I do that using the [meta object protocol](https://docs.perl6.org/language/mop)?

Comment: Rather than trying to work with internals, why don't you use the slightly slower, but more consistent `$*DISTRO.is-win`?  Which you should be able to easily dynamically override?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I can't in this particular case. In fact, that is why I have opened [this issue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2190) in Rakudo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The concept of "class variable" doesn't exist in Perl 6.

The declaration being considered is of a lexical variable, and its lifetime is bound to the scope (bounded by curly braces) that it is declared within. It doesn't have any relationship with the `class` that's being declared, so there's no way to reach it through the MOP. (That the block in this question happens to be attached to a `class` declaration is incidental so far as lexical variables go.) Nor is it declared `our`, so it's not stored in the package either.

The only way a lexical can be accessed - aside from under a debugger - is if something inside of that lexical scope explicitly made it possible (for example, by acquiring a pseudo-package and storing it somewhere more widely visible, or by allowing `EVAL` of provided code). Neither is happening in this case, so the variable not possible to access.

Perl 6 is very strict about lexical scoping, and that's a very intentional part of the language design. It supports the user in understanding and refactoring the program, and the compiler in program analysis and optimization. Put another way, Perl 6 is a fairly static language when it comes to lexical things (and will likely come to do much more static analysis in future language versions), and a dynamic language when it comes to object things.